# Having subtables and subcptions within tabularx environment

Tags: tables, longtable, tabularx, subfloats, subcaption

I am trying to have two large subtables within a tabularx environment, because the two tables are more than a page each. This means that each of them should break and have its own subcaption. I am providing a minimum working example (it has some errors but it compiles) with shorter tables to improve readability, along with some indicators of what I am trying to achieve.

I am following a journal template so I would like to avoid hacks like writing captions manually, if possible. This could have been easily accomplished with `table` but I need **each** table to break. I would be very happy to hear an alternative.

```
\documentclass[12p]{article}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{tabularx,ltablex}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{pbox}
\usepackage{subcaption,booktabs,float}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabularx}

\small

\subfloat{

\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{cccccccccccc}
\toprule
    ~ & XX & XX & XX & XX & ~ & XX & XX & XX & XX \\   
\midrule
\endfirsthead
\toprule
    ~ & XX & XX & XX & XX & ~ & XX & XX & XX & XX \\   
\midrule
\endhead
\midrule
\multicolumn{12}{r}{\footnotesize( To be continued)}
\endfoot
%\bottomrule
\endlastfoot
BBB & \multicolumn{2}{c}{BBBBBB} & ~ & ~ & ~ & \multicolumn{2}{c}{BBBBBB} & ~ \\      \hline
    
    A & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & ~ & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\ 
    A & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & ~ & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\  
    A & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & ~ & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\ 
    A & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & ~ & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\  
    A & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & ~ & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\ 
    A & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & ~ & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\  
    A & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & ~ & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\ 
    A & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & ~ & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\ \hline

\caption{This should be a subcaption: (s) Sth sth sth} 
\end{tabularx}
}

\vspace{2\floatsep}   

\subfloat{

\small
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{cccccccccccc}

\toprule
    ~ & XX & XX & XX & XX & ~ & XX & XX & XX & XX \\  
\midrule
\endfirsthead
\toprule
    ~ & XX & XX & XX & XX & ~ & XX & XX & XX & XX \\  
\midrule
\endhead
\midrule
\multicolumn{12}{r}{\footnotesize( To be continued)}
\endfoot
\endlastfoot

     BBB & \multicolumn{2}{c}{BBBBBB} & ~ & ~ & ~ & \multicolumn{2}{c}{BBBBBB} & ~ \\ \hline
     
    A & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & ~ & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\ 
    A & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & ~ & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\  
    A & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & ~ & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\ 
    A & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & ~ & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\  
    A & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & ~ & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\ 
    A & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & ~ & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\  
    A & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & ~ & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\ 
    A & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & ~ & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\ \hline

\caption{This should be a subcaption: (b) Sth sth sth}        
\end{tabularx}
}

\end{tabularx}

There should be a caption here: Table X: sth sth sth\\ 
  \scriptsize{\textit{Note:} Random notes.}  
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! If I understood you correctly, you like to have two successive `longtable`s with subcaptions and after them main caption?

Comment: @Zarko yes, I believe that would work, although I am not familiar with `longtable`. Many thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Hm, very unusual demands ...
- I don't see, frankly said, any sens for such successive tables.
- Anyway, you should be aware:

  - long tables, which break over pages, had not to be enclosed in any box, like
    you attempt to insert them into `subfloat` which are in `tabularx`
  - In `tabularx` table you should prescribe table width and, as at all tables, desired number of column types
  - In `tabularx` table at least one column should be of `X` or from it derived type.
  - number of columns in table should  complain with number of prescribe in table preamble. In your case, you prescribe 10 columns, but in table you require in a `multicolumn` cells which should span 12 columns
  - `ltablex` redefine width of `X` column width, so if you like to have, that
  - they behaviors as at pure `tabularx` table, than you should add in preamble the command  `\keepXColumns`

Hopefully the following MWE gives something close to what you after:

```
\documentclass[12p]{article}
\usepackage{booktabs, multirow, ltablex}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}
\keepXColumns
\usepackage[skip=1ex]{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{} X cccc c cccc @{}}
\caption*{(a) This should be a subcaption}   \\
\toprule
    ~ & XX & XX & XX & XX & ~ & XX & XX & XX & XX \\
\midrule
\endfirsthead
\caption*{(a) This should be a subcaption}   \\
\toprule
    ~ & XX & XX & XX & XX & ~ & XX & XX & XX & XX \\
\midrule
\endhead
\midrule
\multicolumn{10}{r}{\footnotesize( To be continued)}
\endfoot
%\bottomrule
\endlastfoot
BBB BBB BBB BBB BBB BBB BBB BBB 
      & \multicolumn{2}{c}{BBBBBB} & ~ & ~ & ~ & \multicolumn{2}{c}{BBBBBB} & ~ \\      \hline

    A & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & ~ & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
    A & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & ~ & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
    A & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & ~ & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
    A & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & ~ & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
    A & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & ~ & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
    A & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & ~ & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
    A & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & ~ & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
    A & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & ~ & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\ \hline
    A & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & ~ & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
    A & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & ~ & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
    A & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & ~ & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
    A & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & ~ & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
    A & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & ~ & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
    A & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & ~ & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
    A & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & ~ & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
    A & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & ~ & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\ \hline
    A & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & ~ & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
    A & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & ~ & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
    A & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & ~ & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
    A & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & ~ & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
    A & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & ~ & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
    A & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & ~ & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
    A & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & ~ & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
    A & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & ~ & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\ \hline
    A & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & ~ & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
    A & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & ~ & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
    A & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & ~ & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
    A & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & ~ & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
    A & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & ~ & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
    A & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & ~ & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
    A & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & ~ & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
    A & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & ~ & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\ \hline
    A & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & ~ & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
    A & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & ~ & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
    A & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & ~ & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
    A & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & ~ & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
    A & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & ~ & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
    A & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & ~ & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
    A & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & ~ & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
    A & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & ~ & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\ \hline
    A & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & ~ & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
    A & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & ~ & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
    A & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & ~ & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
    A & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & ~ & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
    A & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & ~ & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
    A & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & ~ & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
    A & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & ~ & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
    A & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & ~ & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\ \hline
\end{tabularx}

\medskip
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{c cccc c cccc}
\caption*{(b) This should be a subcaption} \\
\toprule
    ~ & XX & XX & XX & XX & ~ & XX & XX & XX & XX \\
\midrule
\endfirsthead
\caption*{(b) This should be a subcaption}   \\
\toprule
    ~ & XX & XX & XX & XX & ~ & XX & XX & XX & XX \\
\midrule
\endhead
\midrule
\multicolumn{10}{r}{\footnotesize( To be continued)}
\endfoot
\endlastfoot

     BBB & \multicolumn{2}{c}{BBBBBB} & ~ & ~ & ~ & \multicolumn{2}{c}{BBBBBB} & ~ \\ \hline

    A & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & ~ & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
    A & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & ~ & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
    A & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & ~ & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
    A & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & ~ & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
    A & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & ~ & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
    A & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & ~ & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
    A & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & ~ & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
    A & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & ~ & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\ \hline
    A & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & ~ & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
    A & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & ~ & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
    A & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & ~ & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
    A & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & ~ & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
    A & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & ~ & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
    A & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & ~ & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
    A & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & ~ & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
    A & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & ~ & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\ \hline
    A & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & ~ & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
    A & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & ~ & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
    A & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & ~ & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
    A & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & ~ & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
    A & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & ~ & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
    A & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & ~ & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
    A & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & ~ & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
    A & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & ~ & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\ \hline
    A & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & ~ & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
    A & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & ~ & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
    A & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & ~ & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
    A & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & ~ & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
    A & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & ~ & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
    A & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & ~ & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
    A & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & ~ & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
    A & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & ~ & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\ \hline
    A & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & ~ & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
    A & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & ~ & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
    A & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & ~ & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
    A & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & ~ & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
    A & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & ~ & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
    A & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & ~ & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
    A & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & ~ & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
    A & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & ~ & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\ \hline
    A & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & ~ & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
    A & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & ~ & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
    A & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & ~ & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
    A & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & ~ & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
    A & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & ~ & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
    A & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & ~ & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
    A & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & ~ & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
    A & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & ~ & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\ \hline
\end{tabularx}

\addtocounter{table}{-2}
\captionof{table}{This is main caption}

 \scriptsize{\textit{Note:} Random notes.}
\end{document}
```

*Note*:

- In above MWE the first the first column is of `X` type, consequently table width is equal to `\textwidth` and longer text in the first column is breaking into two lines
- The second table are only `c` columns, so table behaviour as standard `longtable`

[image]

Comment: This solved it, thank you very much! Unfortunately I cannot upvote.

Comment: @Titus, you are welcome. You will able to upvote soon ... after one upvoted question or answer :-)